# Can't upload files via SFTP (freeSSHd) on Windows Server 2008 because of file permissions

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, sftp

I installed freeSSHd today in order to upload files to our webserver which is on a Windows Server 2008. Inside freeSSHd I created a user and gave him the ability to connect and that works fine. I can login and browse the directories but I am unable to upload files as I get permission denied.

As I mainly work with linux and would have used chown for this, what is an easy way to change file permissions? As I can't find the user I created in freeSSHd (guessing it's not a windows user) what group should I set the permissions for?